# Order of instantiation between Val, def, lazy val in Scala

Tags: scala

Can anybody walk me through how this can out vdld pleeease?

```scala
def deflazyval() : Unit = {
  lazy val l : Int ={print("l") ; 5}
  def      d : Int ={print("d") ; 7}
  val      v : Int ={print("v") ; 3}
  
  var s : Int = d
  s += l
  s += v
  s += l
  s += d

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def` gets re-evaluated every time it is used, `lazy val` gets evaluated the first time is used, `val` gets evaluated on its initialization. So:

1. `val v` gets evaluated on its initalization and **prints v**.
2. next, `var s` gets initialized and is assigned `d` which evaluates `def d` and thus **prints d**.
3. then, `lazy val l` is assigned to `s` - this is the first time `l` gets used, so this is when it is evaluated and **prints l**.
4. assigning `v` to `s` prints nothing because the value (3) was stored during the initializaton of `v` (-> step 1).
5. re-assigning `l` to `s` prints nothing because the value (5) was stored during the initializaton of `l` (which happend the first time it was used in step 3).
6. re-assigning `d` to `s` **prints d** because `d` is a `def` and thus gets re-evaluated every time it is called.

(N.B.: since you are using `+=`, it would be more precise to write "`s + x` is assigned to `s`" where I just wrote "`x` is assigned to `s`", but for the question at hand (why things get printed), it does not matter whether you do `v += x` or `v = x`.)